# What is inactive memory and how can I use it?

Tags: mac, memory, macbook

I use a MacBook with 2 Go of RAM. iStats Menu 3 shows me that I have 500 Mb of "inactive memory". When my "disponible memory" (it does not include this inactive memory) is very low, the Mac starts to be slow.

Is there a way to have the Mac use this inactive memory? What is it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also wondered this but a quick Google found this:

> Inactive memory is memory that has
>   previously been used to run an
>   application. OSX keeps certain things
>   in memory just in case you launch the
>   application again, so that it'll
>   launch quicker. However, this inactive
>   memory can be released to a new app as
>   needed.